# Converting Each Element of a Line of a File into an Integer

Tags: c++, string, file

I have a file called numbers.txt, with several lines of numbers. I'm just trying to convert each number to an integer and print that out.

```
if (numbers.is_open()) {
    while (std::getline(numbers, line)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
            number = atoi((line.at(i)).c_str());
            std::cout << number;
        }
    }
    numbers.close();
```

Can someone explain why this doesn't work for me?

Comment: I suggest using `std::istringstream`.  Search StackOverflow for "c++ istringstream getline".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial code shouldn't even compile, because [std::string::at(size_t pos)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/) doesn't return a `std::string`; it returns a primitive character type. Characters have no methods—there isn't a `char::c_str()` method!

If your comment above is correct and you want to treat the individual characters as numbers, I suggest the following:

```
if (numbers.is_open())
{
    while (std::getline(numbers, line))
    {
        auto i = line.begin(), e = line.end(); // std::string::const_iterator
        for (; i != e; ++i)
        {
            if (std::isdigit(*i))
            {
                // Since we know *i, which is of type char, is in the range of
                // characters '0' .. '9', and we know they are contiguous, we
                // can subtract the low character in the range, '0', to get the
                // offset between *i and '0', which is the same as calculating
                // which digit *i represents.
                number = static_cast<int>(*i - '0');
                std::cout << number;
            }
            else throw "not a digit";
        } // for
    } // while
    numbers.close();
} // if
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `for` loop iterates over each character in the line, which is unnecessary, assuming that you want to treat the whole line as a single number. The `atoi()` function operates on a whole c-string, not just a single character. So, you can get rid of the `for` loop and the `.at(i)`, and just do something like this:

```
if (numbers.is_open()) {
    while (std::getline(numbers, line)) {                                     
        int number = atoi(line.c_str());
        std::cout << number << std::endl;                            
    }
    numbers.close();
  }
}
```

EDIT (w.r.t comment #0)

To interpret each character individually, you could do this (although there may be cleaner implementations):

```
if (numbers.is_open()) {
    while (std::getline(numbers, line)) {
      for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {                                                     
        int number = atoi(line.substr(i, 1).c_str());
        std::cout << number << endl;
        }
    }
    numbers.close();
  }
```

If you can guarantee that there will be only numbers in the file, you could also perform the conversion like this:

```
int number = line.at(i) - '0';
```

Comment: I want to treat each character as a single number.